# Is it allowed to convert from int to long at template specialization (should this code compile)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Look at this snippet:

```
template <long>
struct Bar { };

template <typename>
struct Foo;

template <int X>
struct Foo<Bar<X>> { };

Foo<Bar<0>> x;
```

`Bar` has `long` parameter, but `Foo` has `int`. Clang-4/5/6 compiles this, but GCC-6/7/8 doesn't:

```
error: aggregate ‘Foo<Bar<0> > x’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: @rici The question is about whether this error should appear on the first place. That is whether complete Foo specialization should be selected even though types of non-type template parameters are different or not. (accidentally deleted comment)

Comment: @vtt: yes, i read it and now i got it, so i deliberately deleted my comments. Sorry for the noise. Hvd's dup is quite clear.

Comment: @rici Actually you've posted correct comment as my question originally contained quote from wrong part of the standard. And that question that was used as close reason contains the same quote as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand these parts deduction should fail:

- For template classes :

> **14.3.3 Template template arguments [temp.arg.template]**
>
> 3. A template-argument matches a template template-parameter `P` when `P` is at least as specialized as the template-argument `A`. If `P` contains a parameter pack, then `A` also matches `P` if each of `A`’s template parameters matches the corresponding template parameter in the template-parameter-list of `P`. Two template parameters match if they are of the same kind (type, non-type, template), **for non-type template-parameters, their types are equivalent** (14.5.6.1), and for template template-parameters, each of their corresponding template-parameters matches, recursively.

and equivalence is defined as:

> **14.5.6.1 Function template overloading [temp.over.link]**
>
> 5. Two expressions involving template parameters are considered equivalent if two function definitions containing the expressions would satisfy the one-definition rule (3.2)

So since substituting `int` with `long` in function definition will not satisfy one-definition rule template arguments won't match and `Foo` specialization won't be selected.

- For template functions:

> **14.8.2.5 Deducing template arguments from a type [temp.deduct.type]**
>
> 17. If `P` has a form that contains `<i>`, and if the type of `i` differs from the type of the corresponding template parameter of the template named by the enclosing simple-template-id, deduction fails. If `P` has a form that contains `[i]`, and if the type of `i` is not an integral type, deduction fails.

```
template<int i> class A { /* ... */ };

template<short s> void f(A<s>);
void k1() {
    A<1> a;
    f(a); // error: deduction fails for conversion from int to short
    f<1>(a); // OK
}
```